# No events getting logged firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase Analytics. However the problem is that every time I try to log an event, no event is reported (even after enabling debug mode through adb for firebase analytics). This is happening on both emulator and my personal device. I do see a error getting logged in logcat whenever I log an event

> Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getId()' on a null object
>   reference:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfc.zzgl(Unknown
>   Source:32)

My gradle configuration is as follows

Top level build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta02'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Project 's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2"
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    // Paging
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0"
    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Application class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(Utils.fetchDeviceId(this));
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Test");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Test");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Test");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
}
```

Comment: events usually take sometime in the firebase dashboard (up to a day).

Comment: Thanks but I tried using https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode But nothing is showing up on DebugView too

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it ! It was a manifest merger issue. Some services for InstanceID never got added because of which it was failing. Copied the services receivers manually and started working !